# Changes in postgresql.conf won't apply

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

> PostgreSQL 9.2.23 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150
>   623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16), 64-bit

Im try to make changes in `postgresql.conf`.

> effective_cache_size = 3GB

but when I write `SHOW effective_cache_size;` It's still 128MB.
I have reloaded the postgresql, restarted it but it's still using default settings. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe there is a later setting in `postgresql.conf` that overrides your setting. Maybe you edited the wrong file or restarted the wrong server.

Comment: I have checked the file and server. Which setting would cause override? My configuration is: 
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 3GB
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2
work_mem = 5242kB
checkpoint_segments = 32

Comment: Use `pg_settings` to determine where the setting you see comes from.

Comment: `SELECT sourcefile FROM pg_settings;` I used this and it gave me : /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf  this is the file I have edited

Comment: It will also tell you the line number. Check if that is correct. Otherwise, the only remaining possibility is that you restarted the wrong server.

Comment: I see 225 rows.How can I know if it is correct or wrong? I am a newbie  sorry

Comment: Sorry, I meant of course `SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'effective_cache_size';`.

Comment: # The commented-out settings shown in this file (postgresql.conf) represent the default values. - you are removing the # comment after update are you?

Comment: Oh,now it worked thank you Slumdog

Comment: you're welcome, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`sudo vim postgresql.conf` to open up the file with sudo permissions.
`i` to insert/edit.
Do your thing.
`:w!` to save changes.
`:q` to exit editor.
Hope this help.